# Como evitar que meu site caia, ao rodar um script "pesado"?

Tags: php, loop

Tenho um script que percorre um diretório buscando arquivos de vídeo no mesmo e então uso o `shell_exec` com o `ffmpeg` para converter o mesmo, o problema é que meu site está caindo durante a execução do script, após iniciar o mesmo no servidor, o site cai e não é possível acessar até que eu encerre o script, estou usando o Wamp instalado em um Windows Server 2012.

Penso que talvez o problema seja no `memory_limit` no PHP.ini que está em `128m`, mas não sei ao certo, existe alguma solução para evitar que meu site caia durante esse processo?

Este é o meu script resumido:

```
if($handle = opendir($diretorio)){
    while ($entry = readdir($handle)){
        $ext = strtolower(pathinfo($entry, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
        if(in_array($ext, $types)){
            $ep = explode('.', $entry);

            $input = $diretorio.$entry;

            $cmd = $ffmpeg.' -i '.$input.' -hide_banner 2>&1 &';
            $exec = shell_exec($cmd);
            $data = trim($exec);
            $x = getStreams($data);

            $video_key = array_search('Video', array_column($x, 'formato'));
            $video_map = $x[$video_key]["tempo"];
            foreach ($x as $index => $value){

                #esse if se repete mais 4x procurando outros formatos e/ou idiomas
                if($value["formato"] === "Audio" && ($value["idioma"] === "jpn" || $value["idioma"] === "eng")){
                    $audio_map = $value["tempo"];
                    $output_legendado = $dir_original_saida.$ep["0"].".mp4";

                    if (!is_dir($dir_original_saida)) {
                        mkdir($dir_original_saida, 0777, true);
                    }
                    if(!file_exists($output_legendado)){
                        $query = " -sn -map $video_map -map $audio_map -vcodec libx264 -acodec aac -ab 128k -y -movflags +faststart $output_legendado ";
                    }
                }           
            }
            $cmd_con = $ffmpeg." -i $input $query 2>&1 &";
            $out = exec($cmd_con);
            echo "<pre>";
            print_r($out);
            echo "</pre>";      
        }
    }
    closedir($handle);
}
```

Comment: Já tentou executar o código na linha de comando? É sempre bom separar a parte de apresentação da sua página de rotinas diversas. Torne seu código mais testável e modularizado, daí você saberá quais são seus limites

Comment: Tens algum exemplo de como posso rodar esse código na linha de comando @JeffersonQuesado

Comment: Vou precisar de mais espaço do que o disponível em comentário, espera

Answer (score 1):

O primeiro ponto que eu vejo é tentar deixar seu código mais testável, separar ele em unidades menores para saber como cada uma delas se comporta, quanto ela precisa, etc.

Vejo aqui que você itera sobre um diretório, decide se é um arquivo a se tratar e, sendo esse arquivo desejável, verifica se precisa de `query` adicional, criando uma pasta caso não haja. Não sei o que o `ffmpeg ' -i '.$input.' -hide_banner` faz, mas

Daí, chego a conclusão que você precisa de uma lista de funções que podem facilitar sua vida, modularizando o código.

```
// Numa abordagem top-down, as funções não declaradas estão abaixo

function transforma_diretorio_filmes($diretorio) {
    $retornos = array();
    if ($handle = opendir($diretorio)) {
        while ($entry = readdir($handle)) {
            if (arquivo_interessante($entry)) {
                $retornos = executa_ffmpeg($diretorio, $entry);
            }
        }
    }
    return $retornos;
}

function arquivo_interessante($entry) {
     $ext = strtolower(pathinfo($entry, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
     return in_array($ext, $types);
}

function executa_ffmpeg($diretorio, $entry) {
    $query = gera_query($diretorio, $entry);
    $cmd_con = $ffmpeg." -i $diretorio.$entry $query 2>&1 &";
    return exec($cmd_con);
}

function gera_query($diretorio, $entry) {
    $query = "";
    $input = $diretorio.$entry;
    $ep = explode('.', $entry);

    $x = getStreamsFromFFMPEG($input);
    $video_key = array_search('Video', array_column($x, 'formato'));
    $video_map = $x[$video_key]["tempo"];
    foreach ($x as $index => $value){

        #esse if se repete mais 4x procurando outros formatos e/ou idiomas
        if (formato_desejado($value)) {
            $audio_map = $value["tempo"];
            $output_legendado = $dir_original_saida.$ep["0"].".mp4";
            verifica_dir_saida($dir_original_saida);
            if (!file_exists($output_legendado)) {
                $query = " -sn -map $video_map -map $audio_map -vcodec libx264 -acodec aac -ab 128k -y -movflags +faststart $output_legendado ";
            }
        }
    }
    return $query;
}

function getStreamsFromFFMPEG($input) {
    $cmd = $ffmpeg.' -i '.$input.' -hide_banner 2>&1 &';
    $exec = shell_exec($cmd);
    $data = trim($exec);
    return getStreams($data);
}

function formato_desejado($value) {
    return $value["formato"] === "Audio" && ($value["idioma"] === "jpn" || $value["idioma"] === "eng");
}

function verifica_dir_saida($dir_original_saida) {
    if (!is_dir($dir_original_saida)) {
        mkdir($dir_original_saida, 0777, true);
    }
}
```

Note que é o mesmo código que você postou, porém mais fatiado em pedaços menores e mais palatáveis, cada um num nível de abstração mais adequado do que tudo junto. Se essas funções estiver em `my_ffmpeg_functions.php`, então podemos criar um programinha PHP chamado `my_testes.php` para usar essas funções:

```
// estou ignorando as chaves de abrir e fechar do php
include 'my_ffmpeg_functions.php';

transforma_diretorio_filmes("my_movie_dir"); // assumindo 'my_movie_dir' como um valor a ser chamado pelo servidor
```

Tendo tudo montado, podemos começar a rodar na linha de comando. Se não me engano, para chamar o php CLI, basta chamar o executável `php`. Caso ele não esteja dispoível, corrija o `PATH` de modo a encontrar o executável `php.exe`. Daí, é só rodar o seguinte comando na linha de comando para ver se está se comportanto como devia:

```
php my_testes.php
```

Comment: Reeorganizei meu código real conforme o proposto no seu exemplo, e de fato pareceu melhorar um pouco o desempenho do script, mas não consegui rodar o mesmo pelo cmd

Answer (score 0):

Uma saída é, ao invés de executar a tarefa e ficar esperando, seria executar a tarefa em segundo plano e o script ir verificando de tempos em tempos se o processo acabou.

Para isso, você tem os chamados Cron Jobs no Unix e as Tarefas Agendadas do Windows. São comandos ou scripts que rodam de tempos em tempos.

A minha sugestão é, na chamada do script PHP, escrever os caminhos dos arquivos a serem processados num BD, ou mesmo mover os vídeos para uma pasta específica, e o script (.bat no windows ou .sh no unix) fica de tempos em tempos sendo chamado e olhando essa pasta, e se tiver algum arquivo, faz a conversão numa pasta de saída e apaga o original, ou move para uma outra pasta de processados.